# Upgrade source version of DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

What is the best way to upgrade a local development version of DNN source without destroying the database (pages, settings, module settings, etc..)?

I'm currently moving from 07.00.XX to 07.02.00 and there is a tremendous amount of refactoring, seems impossible to just overlay the source.

Is there a way I can do this with preservation of all settings, etc....or will I need to rebuild parts of the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the SOURCE package, you should be able to simply copy the SOURCE files from the ZIP file you download, over all of the existing files.

You might make sure that the new SOURCE package doesn't have a web.config file, if it does, remove/rename that so that it doesn't replace your existing web.config file, and thus saving your MachineKeys and connection strings.

Back up the FILES and Database before you attempt this however, just to be safe.

After the copy you might have to build the solution before the upgrade will work.

I typically don't recommend using the SOURCE package for DNN, unless you absolutely need to make changes (not recommended) to the source, it isn't necessary for doing Module Development or skinning.

Comment: I don't make core changes, I use it for debugging in some cases. The source from these two versions has HEAVY refactoring, the folder structure doesn't resemble the previous version at all. I guess I'm not seeing how it will work when the structures are completely different.

Comment: If you're using it for Debugging, just use the SYMBOLS package (install like you do an extension)

Comment: The symbols package is the answer! Thanks Chris.